# Zend Framework 2 Navigation's exception

Tags: zend-framework2

I was looking for show a navigation menu in the layout.phtml file:

```
<?php echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu(); ?>
```

So, I added these lines to /module/Application/config/module.config.php in order to declare the menu's structure according to my app routes:

```
'navigation' => array(
        'default' => array(
            'place' => array(
                'label' => 'Places',
                'route' => '/place',
                'pages' => array(
                    'country' => array(
                        'label' => 'Countries',
                        'route' => '/place/country',
                    ),
                    'state' => array(
                        'label' => 'States',
                        'route' => '/place/state',
                    ),
                    'city' => array(
                        'label' => 'Cities',
                        'route' => '/place/city',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
     ),
```

and then I wrote a loader for the Zend/Navigation instance:

```
'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
            'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
        ),
    ),
```

but I get repeatedly this exception:

> Fatal error: Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\RuntimeException: Route with
>   name "" not found in
>   C:\wamp\www\bsol\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\AbstractHelper.php
>   on line 471

I attempted to solve the problem adding this line to the menu declaration:

```
             'pages' => array(
                    'route' => '/place',
                    'country' => array(
                        'label' => 'Countries',
                        'route' => '/place/country',
                    ),
```

Nevertheless, In that case I get another different exception:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend\Navigation\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message
>   'Invalid argument: $page must be an instance of
>   Zend\Navigation\Page\AbstractPage or Traversable, or an array' in
>   C:\wamp\www\bsol\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php
>   on line 733

UPDATED: Following Jurian Sluiman's suggestion,

This must be my router configuration (module\Place\config\module.config.php), if I've got a module called 'Place', with 3 controllers (city, country and state):

```
'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'city' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/city[/:action][/:oid]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Place\Controller\City',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),

            'country' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/country[/:action][/:oid]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Place\Controller\Country',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),

            'state' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/state[/:action][/:oid]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Place\Controller\State',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),

        ),
),
```

And this must be my navigation config (actually I located this one in an autoloadable file in /config/autoload/menu.global.php):

```
return array(
    'navigation' => array(
        'default' => array(
            'place' => array(
                'label' => 'Places',
                'route' => 'country',
                'pages' => array(
                    'country' => array(
                        'label' => 'Countries',
                        'route' => 'country',
                    ),
                    'state' => array(
                        'label' => 'States',
                        'route' => 'state',
                    ),
                    'city' => array(
                        'label' => 'Cities',
                        'route' => 'city',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
     ),
);
```

...And now It works!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually routes start not with a `/`. The `/` is a delimiter for route names, so when the `/place` route is assembled, you have a parent `""` and then a child `"place"`. The first one is empty, giving you this error.

Perhaps you confused route names with the route itself. You have to provide the name of the route, so the route itself (the URL) will be returned. So imagine you have this route config:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'place' => array(
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/place',
                'defaults' => array(
                    // Some defaults here
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

In this case, your route **name** is `place` and not `/place`. If you have a different route config then the one here above, put the route config in your question so I can update my answer.

Comment: Yes. You're right. I made some mistakes when I was writing the route config for my module.

Comment: Ahah, this answer helped me as well, when I input the route, it had curly braces in it that broke everything, but the error message was related to their being no "Translator":
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'No translator provided' in` which threw me off alot.